# Google Earth Engine: Chart to Array

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to take the data generated in the doySeries chart and use it as an array of values. Is this at all possible? What I am interested in is using the mean over the years to create a list of cumulative precipitation values that I can then use in another chart as a reference point to identify anomalous days in later years. Below is the script I have so far:

```
var polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[-92.56227555674951,40.858223918075275],
                                   [-92.56227555674951,40.85666590660416],
                                   [-92.56227555674951,40.85666590660416],
                                   [-92.55961480540674,40.85828883442468]]);

var startDateEarly = ee.Date('1981-01-01');
var endDateEarly = ee.Date('1983-12-31');

var chirpsColl = ee.ImageCollection('UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY')
                .filterDate(startDateEarly, endDateEarly)
                .filterBounds(polygon);

var chirpsMean = ui.Chart.image.doySeries({
  imageCollection: chirpsColl,
  region: polygon,
  scale: 1,
  yearReducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  //seriesProperty: 'label'
});
print(chirpsMean);
```

on a side note, is the scale a buffer? If so, if I set it to 0, will it only reduce within my selected region?

Comment: Scale is not a buffer. You can read about EE scale here: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/scale

Comment: Ah, so it's just a pyramid. So that means that if I set it to 0, it will process the data in its native resolution, right?

Comment: @RodrigoE.Principe and Kuik these are both very elaborate answers and I appreciate you taking the time to do this! I have developed an inefficient script that uses arrays to solve the problem, but I will be sure to try both solutions once I am sure my script works and does everything I want it to. This will be the next step in writing a more elegant script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are interested in these kind of graphs, with precipitation per DOY and per year?

```
print(ui.Chart.image.doySeriesByYear(chirpsColl, 'precipitation', polygon, ee.Reducer.mean(), 1, ee.Reducer.mean()));
```

You can get the values as you have in the chart you present in your answer as:

```
// map over the image collection and set Doy and mean precipitation
var mapped = chirpsColl.map(function(image){
  // get the DOY
  var DOY = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('D');
  // parse the Date output to a number
  DOY = ee.Number.parse(DOY).toInt();
  var value = image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), polygon, 1);
  return image.set('precMean', value.get('precipitation')).set('DOY', DOY); 
});

// put the values in a array. Use mean values for images with same DOY
var doys = ee.List.sequence(1,365);
var output = doys.map(function(i){
  //i = ee.Number(i).toInt();
  var valuesPerDOY = ee.List(mapped.filter(ee.Filter.eq('DOY', i)).aggregate_array('precMean'));
  var meanPrec = valuesPerDOY.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
  return meanPrec;
});
print(output);
```

Or, if you want a dictionary output with the values of each year plus the mean value over those years, use:

```
// put the values in a array. Use mean values for images with same DOY
var numberOfYears = ee.Number.parse(ee.Date(chirpsColl.first().get('system:time_start')).format('yyyy')).toInt()
                      .subtract(ee.Number.parse(ee.Date(chirpsColl.sort('system:time_start', false).first().get('system:time_start')).format('yyyy')).toInt()).abs().add(1);

var doys = ee.List.sequence(1,365);
var output = doys.map(function(i){
  var valuesPerDOY = ee.List(mapped.filter(ee.Filter.eq('DOY', i)).aggregate_array('precMean'));
  // some years have 1 less day. Append zero to those lists to have similar lengths
  valuesPerDOY = ee.List(ee.Algorithms.If(valuesPerDOY.length().eq(3), valuesPerDOY, valuesPerDOY.add(0)));
  var meanPrec = ee.Number(ee.Algorithms.If(valuesPerDOY.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()), valuesPerDOY.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()), 0));
  return ee.Dictionary.fromLists(['1981', '1982', '1983', 'mean'], valuesPerDOY.add(meanPrec));
});
print('output as dictionary with years + mean',output);
```

[Link script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/4db4b85cdfdd3fb40f0ddfacd2c7cceb)

Comment: I have tried the former script and it works very well for the area I defined. However, I would now like to look at a much bigger area where the number of pixels exceeds the 10000000 allowed by GEE. Do you know if there is a way around that?

Comment: change the line for value to: var value = image.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: polygon, scale: 1, maxPixels: 10e10}); It will set the maximum allowed pixels to a higher number in the reduceRegion call. Moreover, increase the scale to something like 5500, which I think approaches the native scale of 0.05 arc degrees (but search for that to make sure).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach. Take in count that the array first index is 0 and corresponds to doy 1 (first day of year)

```js
var doySeriesArray = function(imageCollection, region, scale,
                              regionReducer, yearReducer, 
                              startDay, endDay) {
  startDay = startDay || 1
  endDay = endDay || 366
  regionReducer = regionReducer || 'mean'
  yearReducer = yearReducer || 'mean'

  // Add doy to each image in the collection
  var addDoy = function(img) {
    img = ee.Image(img)
    var doy = img.date().getRelative('day', 'year')
    doy = ee.Number(doy).add(1) // somehow gets the first day of the year as 0 and so on..
    return img.set('doy', doy)
  }
  var withDoy = imageCollection.map(addDoy)

  // Reduce over doy
  var doys = ee.List.sequence(startDay, endDay)
  var reduceDoy = function(doy) {
    var filterDoy = withDoy.filterMetadata('doy', 'equals', doy)
    return ee.Image(filterDoy.reduce(yearReducer)).set('doy', doy)
  }
  var reducedDoy = doys.map(reduceDoy)

  // Reduce over region
  var reduceRegion = function(img) {
    img = ee.Image(img)
    var doy = img.get('doy')
    var reduction = img.reduceRegion({
      reducer: regionReducer,
      geometry: region,
      scale: scale
    })
    reduction = ee.Dictionary(reduction)
    return ee.Algorithms.If(reduction.contains('precipitation_mean'),
                            reduction.get('precipitation_mean'),
                            0)
  }

  return reducedDoy.map(reduceRegion)
}

var array = doySeriesArray(chirpsColl, polygon, 1)
print(array)
```

link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/1da18e2a0341ebc14feec723a683e3c1

I have downloaded the CSV from the chart, and as far as I could see the results are the same.