# Accessing data from time series in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, table, time-series, calculate-values

I have a code for NDVI time series from an image collection. This code prints the time series in a table or a chart.
Is there a way to access the values in the table of the time series in google earth engine code? I want to calculate the slope\area between points in the time series in google earth engine enviorment.

Code snippit:

```
    //Export NDVI Time Series into a Scatter Chart and a CSV format              
var TimeSeries = Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
S2_withNDVI, fc, ee.Reducer.mean(), 'NDVI', 3, 'system:time_start', fc_ID)
    .setChartType('ScatterChart')
    .setOptions({
      title: 'NDVI Time Series For Shift 1-2 Argentina',
      vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 4,
      series: {
}});
// Display.
print(TimeSeries);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you print a chart on the console, there is a button to the top right (red circle).

[image]

Click on it to open a new tab. There is another button (red circle) that allows you to download the csv with the NDVI values per date:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know this. Is there a way to have that table in google earth engine and do my analayize in the google earth enviorment?

Comment: The answer to this question may be helpful https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313804/google-earth-engine-chart-to-array